# Password to NTLM from dump file

Tags: c#, powershell

I am in security and want to consume a massive password dump file (3GB) as part of my usual password audits

The file is delimited into two columns, SHA1, and the actual password

For my purposes, because Windows stores password as NTLM hashes at rest (Kerberos only used during transport) I need passwords in NTLM, not SHA1. (You can easily prove it to yourself by doing a password dump, I use DSInternals)

I am currently converting clear-text passwords to NTLM with this script

```
#Install-Module DSInternals
Import-Module DSInternals

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("C:\...\68_linkedin_found_hash_plain.txt")

try {
    for() {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }        
        $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $line.Split(':')[1] -AsPlainText -Force
        $hash = ConvertTo-NTHash $pwd;
    Add-Content C:\...\68_linkedin_ntlm.txt $hash 
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Any obvious way of processing this faster? I suppose I can ingest into a DB and process it threaded via a little C# app but maybe there's something quick and dirty?

The file format is (no these are not my passwords, these are passwords from a common password dump file that is publicly available)

```
8c9fcfbf9ead0d63d04b5d3120c42cb885af899e:16piret
8c9fd045ee531744a4fdc1f52e59c3878e742ee0:louie310
8c9fd070274a0eebecf58f8f50e283bf53cec215:kery62
8c9fd08d1c17266f7c1e42a3f16a1161613c7572:sa81nt
8c9fd1093bd8592bbaea195785f8d1c81589073f:cuchilleros
8c9fd1a963bbf44ea9b531e91e5cb1b591c454cc:198962914685590
8c9fd1d8cc6d4fa8164a2fcb3adc7a45f3409547:sculp1011
8c9fd20540d66831f6f65a39ce1bca0e654fd5e6:ume1431965
8c9fd2b4a9571db21c4226bf9ecaea282ecadd5e:534015629819772
8c9fd2f3e63c20314cc962b624178ba82c6674a7:siegenthaler
8c9fd3713fe9600d2bea05b4e8cd33efe12bddb1:mkenrick
8c9fd3a39cca8fb8cdeeb52999aed7e6e9435fd3:billscot
8c9fd3b96ee1485e0fd7d6c71ffe3efd2e8a4614:ndiyehova
8c9fd43aef9804dab6e0aebc58415543175fea00:662566123
8c9fd481cf8f35edb6ebd683fffb0efce0478f21:371874conv
8c9fd4f37632294093fb057eb0168a05d9396e74:h3aww7w
8c9fd53dce9b046f73c5f298e2f694213f8f90f1:squishy23
8c9fd55206e0525d119f4946d3ae75e347cccb4b:NEH3112
8c9fd555303ac08f9103ff8451f8c05cf48cf120:marco22580
8c9fd5c6a94b1171518d0ba264033d779a075e8c:Nowornever2010
8c9fd613fb632b5bc6ae20a671aa40decdb8609a:MKSmks1976##
8c9fd627a48f9971df5bee874501156e9d3c011d:Steripro5
```

TIA

**EDIT:
By reading into memory and writing to separate files speed up the process a bit. Also used suggestion from TessellatingHeckler**

```
Import-Module DSInternals
$lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines('C:\...\68_linkedin_found_hash_plain.txt')

foreach($line in $lines) {
    try {
        $password = $line.Substring($line.IndexOf(':')+1);
        if ($password.Length -lt 128)
            {
            $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $line.Substring($line.IndexOf(':')+1) -AsPlainText -Force
            $hash = ConvertTo-NTHash $pwd;
            Set-Content C:\Temp\Hashes\$hash.txt $hash
            }
        }
    finally {

    }
}
```

The afterwards I can combine the files with

```
copy *.txt combined.log
```

Answer (score 1):

If those are typical line lengths, and your file is 3GB, we're talking 50-60 million lines.

Change `$line.Split(':')[1]` to `$line.Substring($line.IndexOf(':')+1)`, that will save creating and cleaning up 50 million arrays and 50 million strings of the bit you don't want. (Is that right? Your example file format has the hash on the left, your use of `[1]` will pick the username part?)

PowerShell calling the .Net static methods like `[system.io.file]` is reasonably fast, but these bits:

```
    $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $line.Split(':')[1] -AsPlainText -Force
    $hash = ConvertTo-NTHash $pwd;
    Add-Content C:\...\68_linkedin_ntlm.txt $hash
```

have a huge overhead. Starting and initializing cmdlets costs a lot more than function calls in other languages, and having add-content close/open the file 50 million times adds needless file system overhead. Change that so you open the file once, and write to it in the loop:

```
# before the loop
$outStream = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new(
                 [System.IO.FileStream]::new(
                     'c:\path\output.txt',
                      [system.io.filemode]::OpenOrCreate))

# in the loop
$outStream.WriteLine($hash)

# after the loop
$outStream.Close()
```

The next bit would be to see if you can get the code which does `ConvertTo-SecureString` and `ConvertTo-NTHash` and inline it. I don't know what the NTHash one is, but [ConvertTo-SecureString source is here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/bd6fdae73520931f0d27a29d6290e18761772141/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/security/SecureStringCommands.cs#L212), it's not going to be trivial to wrap / inline that into PowerShell code.

That's it as far as I can see for "quick and dirty", but it might knock some 20-30% off the runtime.

Comment: Currently at 15k per minute. Total record 60525521. Thank you for your suggestions

Comment: @ShaunVermaak might be worth trying it in PowerShell v7 preview 4, if you are still using 5.1 there have been performance improvements in the new versions; Not sure if any would help here, but it can't hurt to try - downloads available from https://github.com/powershell/powershell/releases ; and I wasn't thinking, the [PoshRsJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) module is very easy to use parallelism, if you could offload chunks of the file into Runspace jobs, you could use multiple CPU cores with little more code.